# How do I get AJAX-based long-polling working in Edge?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer, long-polling

I am trying to get a very basic long-polling skeleton to work across browsers. My solution is working just fine in Chrome, but I cannot get it to work in Edge.

In Edge, the page loads without error that I can see (F12 in Edge). However, no request is received at the server (unlike under Chrome). The only traffic shown on the network tab of the browser developer tools is the download of jQuery itself. I can browse directly to the URL I wish to poll and get a result. I've added some console logging and this is what I see in Edge:

```
IIFE
Setting up polling
>> Polling
<< Polling
```

And that's it. On Chrome, those last two lines repeat ad infinitum.

Update: I moved the code and the server from my PC onto a dev server. In this environment the code works on Chrome *and* Edge. I could see network traffic in Edge and got a response from the server. So it seems that the issue relates my local environment, not the javascript per se.

Here's my basic code:

`index.html:`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>AJAX Polling Exploration</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="poll.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
    ...
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

`poll.js:`

```
$(function() {
    console.log('IIFE');
    // Make sure caching is off as many suggest this is required for IE
    $.ajaxSetup ({
        cache: false
    });
    function polling() {
        console.log('>> polling');
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url:  'http://localhost:8080/result',
            cache: false,
            data: { name: 'Test', date: new Date().getTime() }, // Make sure the payload varies - caching again
            success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                // Take action ...
                //setTimeout(polling, 2000); // Apparently this is no good for IE
                setTimeout(function(){ polling(); }, 2000);
            }
        });
        console.log('<< polling');
    }
    //polling();
    console.log('Setting up polling');
    setTimeout(function(){ polling(); }, 2000);
});
```

There are many similar questions on SO on this topic and I have followed their advice to no avail. Specifically: (a) make sure caching is off for IE; and (b) use the correct form for `setTimeout()`.

It should be irrelevant, but just in case, the application at `localhost:8080` is based on Spring and running under Tomcat.

(N.B. Originally my question stated that I couldn't get this to work in IE. I found I was inadvertently using an ancient version of jQuery. Switching to the latest from the Google CDN got things going in IE.)

Comment: `I cannot get it to work` - the solution is *fix it* - sounds simple, but without a useful description of the problem, you won't get a useful answer :p

Comment: @JaromandaX good point, the observed behaviour was missing. I've added this now.

Comment: `no request is received at the server` - can you observe the request is being sent by the client?

Comment: @JaromandaX I'm not sure. What would be the easiest way to see this?

Comment: browser developer tools network tab

Comment: Can you actually hit the target URL normally from a Microsoft browser? If not could be a proxy issue? Have you run fiddler or wireshark to monitor the network traffic to see if there are any other issues?

Comment: @JaromandaX I've checked the network tab and I see traffic under Chrome but not under Edge.

Comment: @JonP Yes, I can hit the underlying target(s) directly from Edge and I see network traffic and get a response. So it seems the XHR call is never made??

Comment: This is where you need [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) or similar to inspect the network traffic with your script. It wouldn't hurt to throw a couple of `console.log` statements in `polling` to make sure it's being called as you expect

Comment: @JonP I've added some console logging. Surprisingly, `polling()` is being called, but just the once and seemingly not having any effect.

Comment: Add `error` and `complete` with some more console logging to try and narrow down the issue : http://api.jquery.com/Ajax_Events/

Comment: Something like: https://jsfiddle.net/4vL943bn/

Comment: I've added `error` and `complete` but no joy, they are never called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the suggestion of one of my colleagues, I moved the application and web pages to a development server, ie. away from my PC and URLs with localhost in them. Lo and behold, the polling code worked just fine under Edge (and Chrome et al).

So it would seem that Edge on my PC has issues with localhost. I've tried a few things on the basis of this knowledge but I haven't been able to figure out the underlying cause.

However, it would seem the code in the question is just fine after all.

Comment: If anyone has any thoughts on the underlying problem, I'd love to hear them.